# Error launching python app after packaging with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I recently have been trying to package one of my python scripts through pyinstaller. I can successfully run the `pyinstaller nameofmyfile.py` command in terminal, but when I go into my project file to launch the app that pyinstaller created, I get this error:

```
f:~ Alex$ /Users/Alex/Desktop/sssss/build/main/main ; exit;
[25457] Error loading Python lib '/Users/Alex/Desktop/sssss/build/main/Python': dlopen: dlopen(/Users/Alex/Desktop/sssss/build/main/Python, 10): image not found
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

After doing a bit of digging it looks like when other people get this error, it is because they are using a later version of python which pyinstaller doesn't support. I then tried using pyenv to package my script with an earlier, supported version of python, but I still get the error above. Does anyone have any ideas on how I could fix this?

I am on maxOSX by the way.